# What is virtual directory? What's the use of it?

Tags: virtual-directory

Please someone explain to me by example what is a virtual directory and why do we need it?

Comment: If only StackOverflow searched google as well as its own question DB when suggesting prior questions...

Comment: @skaffman: +1 Nice idea - one for uservoice I think.

Comment: @phoenix: Stack Overflow is for everyone. Any programming question is allowed. Find another outlet for your RTFM spam.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A virtual directory is a friendly name, or alias, either for a physical directory on your server hard drive that does not reside in the home directory.
Because an alias is usually shorter than the path of the physical directory, it is more convenient for users to type.

Taken from [here](http://windowsitpro.com/article/articleid/15605/iis-101-using-virtual-directories.html)

Comment: The primary benefit was abstraction enabling reuse and complex hosting structures, I think the convenience aspect was tertiary or less :)

Answer (score 12):

In essence, in IIS, it's like a shortcut to another directory on your computer while seeming like it is a subdirectory of the current directory.

I.E.

www.example.com/bob/phil

bob may be a subdirectory of the root, while phil is a directory elsewhere on the computer, not necessarily in bob

Answer (score 0):

Virtual directory in a directory that is created in IIS to host a local application or go to a particular folder on the server physical or virtual directory is created .

For example: in the development team , if you wish to receive your application, you must create a virtual directory and specify the physical path.

You can create the virtual directory, click the IIS and selecting from the context menu.

[3100 Dumps PDF](http://www.dumpspdf.com/3100.html)

Answer (score 0):

A web application is accessed using a virtual directory name instead of a physical folder name. For example, if you have a web application called "Shopcart" in your machine, you will have a virtual directory for this web application. You will access your web application using the URL . If your virtaul directory name is "Test", then your web application url will be "http://localhost/Test".